# Manipulating infinitesimals - what is wrong with this argument?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, infinitesimals

Now I know that $dy/dx$ is not a fraction etc., but if you look at the works of 17th -- early 19th century mathematicians you'll see they played fast & loose with their infinitesimals and arrived at correct results.

I tried to give that a go on a differential equation, and I think I obtained an incorrect result. My problem is I can't give an argument as to why any of the steps are illegal. Can anyone help me? Here's the derivation:

---

A point mass $M$ fixed at the origin gravitationally attracts another point mass. The motion of the test mass satisfies:

$$ \ddot{\boldsymbol r} = -\frac{gM\hat{\boldsymbol r}}{r^2} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

The acceleration vector in polar coordinates is given by

$$ \ddot{\boldsymbol r} = (\ddot r - r\dot\varphi^2)\hat{\boldsymbol r} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot\varphi)\hat{\boldsymbol\varphi} $$

Plugging that in \eqref{1} and equating like components we get that the $\hat{\boldsymbol\varphi}$ component is zero, which implies

$$ r^2\frac{d\varphi}{dt} = k \tag{2}\label{2} $$

a constant. So we only have the radial equation:

$$ \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} - r\left(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\right)^2 = -\frac{gM}{r^2} $$

Let's try and prove that this is a conic. We'll use \eqref{2}, rewritten as

$$ \frac{r^2\,d\varphi}{k} = dt $$

to get rid of the $dt$'s in the equation. Also, as long as we're playing "$dy/dx$ is a fraction", we may as well go ahead and expand that squared derivative:

$$ \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} - \frac{r\,d\varphi^2}{dt^2} = -\frac{gM}{r^2} $$

Now rewriting $dt^2$ as $r^4\,d\varphi^2/k^2$ in the above,

$$ \frac{k^2\,d^2r}{r^4\,d\varphi^2} - \frac{k^2r\,d\varphi^2}{r^4\,d\varphi^2} = -\frac{gM}{r^2} $$

$$ \frac{d^2r}{r^4\,d\varphi^2} - \frac{r\,d\varphi^2}{r^4\,d\varphi^2} = -\frac{gM}{k^2r^2} $$

$$ \frac{d^2r}{d\varphi^2} - \frac{r\,d\varphi^2}{\,d\varphi^2} = -\frac{gMr^2}{k^2} $$

$$ \frac{d^2r}{d\varphi^2} = -\frac{gMr^2}{k^2} + r $$

Now, this equation already seems to be wrong. It still holds for a circular orbit (don't forget that $k=r^2\dot\varphi$ though), but I don't think it holds for other conics. Moreover, I worked a bit more on this equation (now with more "conservative" steps) and in more than one way arrived at equations that IIRC the general solutions of which are in terms of elliptic functions (and didn't seem to necessarily reduce to something simpler). See:

(1) If the solution is a conic then

$$ r = \frac{ep}{1-e\cos\varphi} $$

and thus

$$ \frac{d^2r}{d\varphi^2} = \frac{2e^3p-e^2p\cos\varphi-e^3p\cos^2\varphi}{(1-e\cos\varphi)^3} $$

but, abbreviating $gM/k^2$ with $a$,

\begin{align}
-ar^2 + r &= -\frac{ae^2p^2}{(1-e\cos\varphi)^2} + \frac{ep}{1-e\cos\varphi} \\
&= \frac{-ae^2p^2(1-e\cos\varphi)+ep(1-e\cos\varphi)^2}{(1-e\cos\varphi)^3} \\
&= \frac{-ae^2p^2+ae^3p^2\cos\varphi+ep+e^3p\cos^2\varphi-2e^2p\cos\varphi}{(1-e\cos\varphi)^3} \\
&= \frac{(ep-ae^2p^2)+(ae^3p^2-2e^2p)\cos\varphi+e^3p\cos^2\varphi}{(1-e\cos\varphi)^3}
\end{align}

Now we must have these two equal. But the coefficients of the cosine-squared terms can only match if $e=0$ or $p=0$. So general conics don't satisfy the eq.

(2) In $r''=-ar^2 + r$, complete the square on the RHS to arrive at something like $r''=-A\rho^2 + B$. We'll have $d\rho/dr=1$ so the eq. is

$$ \rho'' = A\rho^2 + B $$

Multiply by $\rho'$ on both sides and integrate,

$$ \frac{1}{2}\rho'^2 = 2A\rho^3 + B\rho + C $$

Separate the variables:

$$ \frac{d\rho}{\sqrt{4A\rho^3 + 2B\rho + C}} = d\varphi $$

Integrating again the LHS becomes an elliptic integral in general. So, incorrect.

---

Where is the illegal step and why is it illegal? Or is the mistake somewhere else?

Comment: Your tangential part of acceleration is wrong.

Comment: Oops... you mean that $1/4$ over there should be a $1/r$? Nice catch. Though I don't think this affects the proof -- the tangential component of acceleration remains 0. I'm updating the OP though.

Comment: Look up the binet equation related to time independent order differential equation.

Comment: $d^2r/dt^2$ is not $d^2r/(dt)^2$ you need to use the chain rule.

Comment: You mean something like $d^2r/dt^2 = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dr}{d\varphi}\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\right)$?

Comment: I have not read all the details of your post, but basically, manipulating things algebraically in a naive way leads to problems with higher order derivatives. But the issues can be avoided, too. Details are discussed in the recently-popular-on-the-internet paper: "Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials" by Bartlett and Khurshudyan. One version can be found on the arXiv at [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09553) and another is on the site for the journal "Dynamics of Continuous, Discrete and Impulsive Systems" [here](http://online.watsci.org/contents2019/v26n3a.html).

Answer (score 1):

If $r(t)=u(φ(t))$, then $\dot r(t)=u'(φ(t))\dotφ(t)$. With the next $t$ derivative you also need to apply the product rule
$$
\ddot r(t)=u''(φ(t))\dotφ(t)^2+u'(φ(t))\ddotφ(t).
$$

While a lot can be done working with infinitesimals $dt,dr,dφ$ if one exactly defines how they relate to each other, working with higher order difference operators with infinitesimal step size is not that easy.

One trap is to reuse the same letter for a different function. $r$ depends on $t$, not on $φ$, thus the expression $\frac{dr}{dφ}$ is ambiguous. While it still makes sense if both are functions of $t$, to switch to a depencence $r=u(φ)$ requires some inverse function argument and a new letter for the new functional relation.

Comment: Hummmm. What exactly means "ambiguous"? Could you give an example of some correct infinitesimal manipulation involving higher order derivatives?

Comment: Essentially that reduces to manipulations with truncated Taylor series. There is also a practical effect to that as you can efficiently implement the expansions of all the elementary "pocket calculator" functions and thus also of most finitely composed functions. See automatic/algorithmic differentiation where details of that are explained.

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to OP who helps me a lot with this.

Your radical substitution where the differentials are treated as fractions are correct, when $r$ is treated as a constant. You can actually check by more conservative methods.
$$
\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d r}{dt}\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d r}{d\varphi}\cdot\frac{d\varphi}{dt} \right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d r}{d\varphi}\cdot\frac{k}{r^2} \right)=\frac{k}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\varphi}\left(\frac{d r}{d\varphi} \right)\cdot \frac{d\varphi}{dt}=\frac{k^2}{r^4}\frac{d^2r}{d\varphi^2}.
$$

However, in general, we have

$$
\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d r}{dt}\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d r}{d\varphi}\cdot\frac{d\varphi}{dt} \right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d r}{d\varphi}\cdot\frac{k}{r^2} \right)=\frac{k}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\varphi}\left(\frac{d r}{d\varphi} \right)\cdot \frac{d\varphi}{dt}-\frac{2k}{r^3}\frac{dr}{d\varphi}=\frac{k^2}{r^4}\frac{d^2r}{d\varphi^2}-\frac{2k}{r^3}\frac{dr}{d\varphi}.
$$
The second term of this does not show up in your radical method, so the final result is incorrect.

However, $dr/d\varphi$ is zero when the orbit is a circle, so your equation is satisfied by a circle.

Your tangential components of the acceleration seems to be wrong
$$
\frac{d^2\mathbf{r}}{dt^2}=(\ddot r - r\dot\varphi^2)\hat{\boldsymbol r}+(r\ddot \theta + 2\dot r \dot\varphi)\hat{\boldsymbol \varphi}.
$$
For a proof, follow this [Link](http://www.grputland.com/2013/12/self-contained-derivation-of-keplers-laws-from-newtons-laws.html#coord20131208).

In your equation, you write $\frac{1}{4}\frac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot\varphi)\hat{\boldsymbol\varphi}=\frac{1}{4}r(r\ddot \theta + 2\dot r \dot\varphi)\hat{\boldsymbol \varphi}$ instead, which differs from the first equation by a factor of $(1/4)r$. However, that does not affect your results, since they are equavalent when set to zero, in your situation.

Comment: I wrote $\hat{\boldsymbol r}$, with the hat, the unit vector in the radial direction $= \boldsymbol r/r$.

Comment: Sorry. I will check it again.

Comment: Hadn't seen this -- no notifications when someone edits a post! Another poster remarked at how I had written the tangential component of acceleration incorrectly. (I edited the OP and fixed it). Though I think this mistake is inconsequential, since we don't use the tangential component of acceleration anyway, only use the fact that $r^2\dot\varphi = \text{const.}$ (which it is regardless of that factor of $r/4$). I'll take a look at your proof of the correctness of the substitution.

Comment: Regarding your proof using conservative methods: in the step in which you pass from $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d r}{d\varphi}\cdot\frac{k}{r^2} \right)$ to $\frac{k}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\varphi}\left(\frac{d r}{d\varphi} \right)\cdot \frac{d\varphi}{dt}$, it seems that you are assuming $k/r^2$ is a constant, but it is not. If this proof is indeed incorrect, then it actually should hint at what is wrong with my derivation.

Comment: @whatadisgrace Ok, finished my edit.